# How to include a Google Sheets cell reference in URL for ImportXML

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I have this ImportXML formula :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=2018-04-01"; "//a[@href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&to=USD']")
```

I want the value of the parameter "&date=" to be replaced by a cell reference (B1).

I've tried this :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date="&B1"; "//a[@href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&to=USD']")
```

But Google Sheet gave me an error. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when `"https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date="&B1` is used, `2018-04-01`of "B1" may be converted to the serial number. And please remove `"` of  `&B1";`. So how about these modifications? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" & TO_TEXT(B1) ; "//a[@href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&to=USD']")
```

or

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" & TEXT(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd") ; "//a[@href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&to=USD']")
```

#### References :

- [TO_TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285?hl=en)
- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

In your question, `=IMPORTXML("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=2018-04-01"; "//a[@href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&to=USD']")` returns the same values like `1.232118 1.232118`. So this is not due to `date=" & TO_TEXT(B1) ;`. It is considered that this is due to the xpath. I couldn't notice that this is your another issue from your question. I'm really sorry. So I updated the xpath.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date= & TO_TEXT(B1) , "//tr[1]//a[@href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&to=USD']")
```

#### Note :

- There are 2 `<td class='rtRates'><a href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&amp;to=USD'>` in the URL. So 1st one is retrieved in this modification. When you want to 2nd one please use `=IMPORTXML("https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date= & TO_TEXT(B1) , "//tr[position()>1]//a[@href='http://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=EUR&to=USD']")`

If I couldn't notice something yet and I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, it worked!

But that's weird; the import gives me twice the same value.

Ref --> http://screenshare.novadmedias.com/1L2y0h1C1Y0Y

Do you understand why?

Comment: @Marty I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot ! yes makes sense!